# Best Practice for jQuery Compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this jQuery to add a back to top button. It's simple and works very well. I have it running as a plugin in WordPress MultiSite on probably 120 websites. Today I noticed it isn't working on every site. There are no console errors, but my guess is that some other plugin or script is causing a conflict. This is inconsistent from one site to the other and I can't find a reason.

How can I write this jQuery so it doesn't experience compatibility issues?

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    $(".scrollToTop").fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $(".scrollToTop").fadeOut();
                }
            });

            //Click event to scroll to top
            $(".scrollToTop").click(function(){
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
                return false;
            });

        });
```

Example site 1: http://anntowergallery.com/exhibits/ Doesn't work.

Example site 2: http://iemajen.com/asphaltanimals/ Works

I've tried this out on a dozen sites or so and cannot pin point what could cause the problem. No errors in console on the gallery website.

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Do the different sites use different versions of jQuery? If you put a breakpoint in your function, does it get called on the sites that don't work?

Comment: I would say no. This particular site http://iemajen.com/lexingtonhabitatforhumanity/services/how-to-apply/ is built using the same theme as http://iemajen.com/asphaltanimals/services/commercial/ - The theme is based on http://themble.com/bones/ and all the sites I use it on are child themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange bug you got there.

Seems that in site 1 you have the following CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

When that CSS is in place, the `$(window).scroll` event listener won't fire. If you remove that CSS line, the JS works just fine.

You can also bind the scroll event to the `body` instead of the `window`:

```
$("body").scroll(function(){
    ...
});
```

But I recall that had some issues with IE. Probably you'd be safest to bind both `$("body").scroll` and `$(window).scroll`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).add("body").scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $(".scrollToTop").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(".scrollToTop").fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $(".scrollToTop").click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you jehna1. Omitting the `overflow-x: hidden;` did the trick. That was used for mobile so I just moved it to a new breakpoint. 

I added the code, but it works without. Is there an advantage / disadvantage to using that?

Comment: @jarmerson I'd say it's better to have a foolproof code if someone someday adds another `overflow-x: hidden;` style.

Comment: I tried your code before changing the CSS and it made no difference.

Comment: @jarmerson hmm, which browser are you testing with? I found it should work at least on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Chrome. I emulated and you're correct it doesn't work in Firefox 7

Comment: How do I work around the `overflow-x:hidden'` thing?

Comment: Just to clarify why I accepted your answer, `overflow-x: hidden;` solved the problem regardless of what code I'm using.

Comment: @jarmerson I tested with latest Chrome, Firefox 44 and IE11 and all of them seem to work just fine with my code (tested on example site 1). I edited the answer to include the full code at the bottom.

Comment: @jarmerson is there some specific browser that doesn't work for you? Or are you getting any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a `style` element inside the `body` tag right before your scroll script, which isn't valid and may be preventing the script from executing. Try moving that into the `head`.

This is the part I'm talking about:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .scrollToTop {
        /* ... */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Yeah I have some messy stuff laying around.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've moved a few things around so the CSS loads in the head on all my sites.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use that code on mobile devices... every tick of the window scroll is firing either a `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`. It would be better to add a flag to check if the scroll to top button is visible, or not ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/n1y9n39s/))

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var visible = false;
  //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (!visible && scrollTop > 100) {
      $(".scrollToTop").fadeIn();
      visible = true;
    } else if (visible && scrollTop <= 100) {
      $(".scrollToTop").fadeOut();
      visible = false;
    }
  });

  //Click event to scroll to top
  $(".scrollToTop").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
    return false;
  });

});
```